Google Apps Script Protected Sheet Edit Permissions
I have developed a google sheet apps script based data collection tool. To give a simplified context, I have a modal form for lets say user registration where users who are given edit access to the sheet can submit data through the form.
I have a script that takes the form data and appends to a hidden sheet that is protected and only I have edit access so that users can not look at other user information or edit their information on their own.
However when user submits the form the data is not getting ultimately appended to that protected sheet with the following error:
Error adding data: You are trying to edit a protected cell or object. Please contact the spreadsheet owner to remove protection if you need to edit.
I was expecting that since I am the owner of the google sheet and the apps script project, the scripts shall execute and data should get appended to my own protected sheet.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Hm, off the top of my head I couldn't say for sure, but if it is a modal, there is a tricky thing to it. With deployed Modals and Sidebars, the effective user interacting with the served HTML of the Modal or Sidebar is actually the account who is logged into the browser.
So, if you have multiple browser profiles, you may want to verify that the browser profile that has the sheet open matches the account that is the sheet owner (can be 2 separate accounts).
The Modal will default to that browser user account.
Check that my friend and reply with what you find!

Thank you for your response! I checked and I am using another account of mine signed in another browser window to access the google sheet and test the form entry as a use case of a real user. Some deepdive google searches have led me to believe that since I have manual set protection on the sheet edit access to only my account, the script when triggered from a user form submit instance is not executing since the user does not have edit permission on the protected sheet. Beats me why this needs to be the case X(

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
